# Optimal font size for a mobile webpage

Tags: css, mobile, html, font-size

I know this question has been asked many times but I couldn't find a solution.
I am designing a web page just for mobile phones. 
I have tried to use `px, pt, percentage, em, vw, medium` but none of these gave me the optimum solution. I am testing it with iPhone 5, Android 4.0.3, Android 4.4.3 and Android 5.1.1

Do you have any solutions for my case?

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7820/font-size-for-mobile-sites

Comment: I tried that too. Sorry I just forgot to add.

Comment: Use media queries for different sizes. Usually em is the best

Comment: I will have to do it I guess. Thnx @RachelGallen

Answer (score 0):

I have used "vw" in responsive design and has worked a treat for me. Tested on android & IPhone. What is causing you the issue? Or can you give some more info on what the optimum result would be?

Comment: 2vw is okay for my body even if it is big for Htc Sensation which is Android 4.4.3. It is fine.  However, in my address part, 2vw is too small in Android 5.1.1 but it is okay for Iphone 5 and 6. I can't even understand that how the same font size is giving me a different size in the same page but in different asp files.

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect answer for your question. You need to find the correct solution to your specific requirements on your own.

Whatever road you go down, don't use fixed sizes like "px"! I would suggest you go with

```
font-size: medium;
```

as a start. Then test for a few devices in your emulators. You might want to read on here:

https://www.feedthebot.com/mobile/legible-font-size.html

http://typecast.com/blog/a-more-modern-scale-for-web-typography

https://www.feedthebot.com/mobile/legible-font-size.html